# Not able to set custom 404 page (Django 1.9)

Tags: django

I'm not able to set a custom 404 page in my application. I know there are many such answers around and I've read a few but they didn't help. Specifically, I tried setting the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `['*']`, adding `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False` and adding `--insecure` to `runserver`. Both these didn't help.

Here are the steps I followed:

Created the page `ankblog/not_found.html`.

Added this to my `views.py`:

```
def not_found(request):
    return render(request, 'ankblog/not_found.html')
```

Added this to my `urls.py`:

```
from ankblog import views as ank_view
handler404 = 'ank_view.not_found'
```

In `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # also tried 'localhost'
```

I'm getting a 500 server error instead of the expected page. Also, if I change `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `['localhost']` I get a 400 error (on accessing any page, so I guess it's a mistake in general).

I'm pretty sure it's small thing I'm missing somewhere but not sure what. Please help!

Comment: If you turn on the debug mode again, and try to reach a non existing url, do you still get the 500 error? Or do you get the usual 404 Django debugging template?

Comment: @Railslide Yes, then I get Django's development 404 template.

Comment: Is ank_view.py in the top level of your project? Maybe it needs to be `ankblog.ank_view.not_found` following the pattern `app.file.method`

Comment: @dotcomly Nice, that solved it! Since I had imported my view as `ank_view` in the file, I thought that `ank_view.not_found` would be sufficient. Changing to the full module path `ankblog.views.not_found` did the trick. Can you please explain why this might be, and add this as your answer below? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import is not even necessary since handler404 is just a variable/setting stored as a string so you can remove it. You just need to provide a full include path in the format `app.file.method` which in your case is `ankblog.views.not_found`.

Comment: Thanks! Goes on to show how trying to be too clever can get you screwed! :D